# Dreamweaver CS6 - Not opening Header.php

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I am having a weird and random problem with Dreamweaver CS6 that I hope you guys will be able to help me out with.

In a nutshell, I am running WAMP and have a test version of Wordpress (latest) installed. I have a theme I am customising installed too. My problem is I can't get Dreamweaver to open up the Header.php file, when I click to open it the whole thing crashes.

It has no problem opening any other php file in the whole installation.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: open it up in notepad, and see if you can re-save as php or evan html for testing purposes

Comment: have you tryed it opening it code mode only? (not split or design mode)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, use Notepad++ to open it.

Now that I'm on a Mac, I totally miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to re-save but no luck. I am just editing in Notepad for now and saving my progress that way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Dreamweaver bug. I put in a bug report for it, but still have not seen a fix. The latest Dreamweaver update makes it so the program does not fully crash, but it still freezes for like at least 20 seconds.

I've had it happen on two separate projects with a "inc.header.php" file..

EDIT: It looks like it may have to do with including Google Web Fonts in the header. I took out the 3 links to http://fonts.googleapis.com and the file is now opening. I'm putting in another bug for this specifically..